# Cakephp : display data in a table with other table's data

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.x

I'm displaying my users in a table, and I am retrieving the company name and city with company_id

users :

```
id  lastname    firstname   company_id  role
1   doe         john        2           author
2   deo         jenne       2           admin
3   deus        Joe         1           admin
4   Stewart     Rob         1           author
```

companies :

```
id  name                city
1   New-York Company    New-York
2   Paris Company       Paris
```

user display :

```
            <?php 
                foreach($users as $user):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $user->lastname?></td>
                    <td><?= $user->firstname?></td>
                    <td><?= $user->companies->name ?></td>
                    <td><?= $user->companies->city?></td>
                    <td><?= $user->role?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
```

usersTable.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config){
        $this->belongsToMany('Companies');
        $this->belongsTo('Companies', [
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
    ]);
}

}       

?>
```

So in my company display, I would like to retrieve admin and author names, like so :

```
                <?php 
                foreach($companies as $company):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $company->name?></td>
                    <td><?= $company->city?></td>
                    <td><?= $company->users-> *adminlastname* ?></td>
                    <td><?= $company->users-> *adminfirstname* ?></td>
                    <td><?= $company->users-> *authorlastname* ?></td>
                    <td><?= $company->users-> *authorfirstname* ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
```

I have tried getting company id to reference company_id in users for starters to get on track, without success(trying to get property of non-object)

Furthermore, would it work if I have several authors and admins ? Less likely to several admins per companies, but can happen, and several authors  is definetely possible

companiesTable :

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class companiesTable extends Table
{

public function initialize(array $config){
    //$this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->hasMany('Users');
    $this->hasMany('companies', [
        'foreignKey' => 'identite',
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Admins', [
'className' => 'Users',
'conditions' => [
    'Admins.role' => 'admin'
    ]
]);

$this->hasMany('Authors', [
     'className' => 'Users',
    'conditions' => [
        'Admins.role' => 'author'
    ]
]);


}

public function isOwnedBy($companyId, $userId){
    $company = $this
        ->find('all',['conditions' => ['companies.id'=>$companyId]])
        ->matching('Users', function ($q) use ($userId) {
            return $q->where(['Users.id' => $userId]);
        })
        ->first();
    if ($company) return true;
    return false;


}




 }
```

Edit : adding Companies/index.ctp, still too new, I do not see at all what's wrong... :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-4 small-12 columns">
        <div style="padding: 22px;">
            <h2>companies</h2>

        </div>

    <div id="customAdd" style="clear:both;padding: 22px;">
            <a href="/companies/add" class="button secondary right" data-reveal-id="Modal" data-reveal-ajax="true">add</a>          
 <div style="clear:both;height:0px;"></div>
    </div>



         <div id="customSearch" style="clear: both;padding: 22px">
            <p style="font-size:36px;    display: inline-block;">search for a company</p><input type="text" id="searchBox">
        </div>


    </div>
     <div class="medium-8 small-12 columns">
        <div>

             <table id="companies" class="cell-border dataTable no-footer">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>city</th>
                        <th>last name</th>
                        <th>first name</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php foreach ($company->users as $user):?> 

                    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href="/companies/edit/<?= $company->id?>">

                  <td><?= $company->name?></td>
                  <td><?= $company->city?></td>
                  <td><?= $company->users[0]->lastname?></td>
                  <td><?= $company->users[0]->firstname?></td>

                  </tr>
                  <?php endforeach;?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting these errors :

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: company [APP/Template/Companies/index.ctp, line 36]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Template/Companies/index.ctp, line 36]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Template/Companies/index.ctp, line 36]
```

which corresponds to this :

```
 <?php foreach ($company->users as $user):?>
```

CompaniesController :

```
 <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;


class CompaniesController extends AppController{

    public function index(){
        $companies = $this->Companies
            ->find('all',['order' => ['Companies.name' => 'ASC']]);
         $this->set(compact('companies'));

         $this->loadModel('Users');
        $users = $this->Users->find('all')
            ->contain(['companies']);
        $this->set(compact('users'));




    }

    public function view($id = null){
        $company = $this->Companies->get($id);
        $this->set(compact('company'));
    }

     public function add(){
        $company = $this->Companies->newEntity();
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {

             if ($this->Companies->save($company)) {

                 $this->Flash->success(__('Your company has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
             }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your company.'));
        }
        $this->set('company', $company);

         $this->set(compact('companies'));
    }

     public function edit($id = null){
        $company = $this->Companies->get($id);
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $company = $this->Companies->patchEntity($company, $this->request->data,['associated' => ['Users']]);


            if ($this->Companies->save($company)) {



                $this->Flash->success(__('Your company has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }

             $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your company.'));
        }


        $this->set('company', $company);

        $this->set(compact('companies'));

    }

    public function delete($id){
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
         $company = $this->Companies->get($id);
         if ($this->Companies->delete($company)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The company with id: {0} has been deleted.', h($id)));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
     }

     public function isAuthorized($user){
         if ($this->request->action === 'logout') {
            return true;
        }
         if ($this->request->action === 'settings') {
            return true;
         }
          return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }
 }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you cannot define multiple associations with the same name. Given that you have a `company_id` field, that is a `belongsTo` association from the users point of view.

Given these prerequisites, it's naturally a `hasMany` association from the companies point of view. I assume that you've set that up already in your `CompaniesTable` class, if not, then that's what you need to do first.

The `users` property will then be an array of `User` entitiy objects, so you need to access it accordingly, that is either directly via an index:

```
$company->users[0]->firstname
```

or by iterating over it:

```
foreach ($company->users as $user) {
    // $user->firstname
}
```

If you need to handle the users separated by their roles, then you could for example filter them accordingly:

```
$admins = collection($company->users)->filter(function ($user) {
    return $user->role === 'admin';
});
```

or maybe better yet create separate associations using conditions:

```
$this->hasMany('Admins', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'conditions' => [
        'Admins.role' => 'admin'
    ]
]);

$this->hasMany('Authors', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'conditions' => [
        'Admins.role' => 'author'
    ]
]);
```

That way you could contain and access the different types of users separately:

```
$company->admins
```

```
$company->authors
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Eager Loading Associations Via Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain)**

Comment: Mmmh I'm getting an invalid argument supplied for foreach using `foreach ($company->users as $user){`

Comment: Then `users` is not what you think it is, most like because you havent contained the association. @Nolan.K

Comment: thanks, added my companiesTable. Trying to figure what users is then

Comment: I'm getting  `Undefined variable: company` before  `invalid argument supplied for foreach` ?

Comment: I don't get it. In my CompaniesController index I call `$this->loadModel('Users');
  $users = $this->Users->find('all');
  $this->set(compact('users'));` , in CompaniesTable I use `hasMany('Users');` so why

Comment: I can only comment on the code I'm seeing, and with the shown example in your question, that error wouldn't occour. May you're accessing `$company` outside the loop, I don't know. Also the snippet you're showing in your comments sets a `users` view variable, which has nothing do with this - not sure what it's good for. @Nolan.K

Comment: Mmmh any idea where I should look up or what additionnal code would help finding where's the issue ? I will try looking it up after sleep ?

Comment: The error message should come with a filename and a line number. @Nolan.K